# Capturing an event with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-capturing

I got a double event to manage. The two events are both "click" and they're handled with jquery. The html is the following:

```
 <div class="siteMap"  style="width:23%;">
            <h5>Divisione Anticontraffazione</h5>
            <span class="menufooter">
            <span class="link1"><a href="#scheda1">Introduzione</a></span><br>
            <span class="link2"><a href="#scheda2">Filosofia</a></span><br>
            <span class="link3"><a href="#scheda3">Negozio online</a></span></span><br>
        </div>
```

Then i have my click events which fires inside the menufooter span and inside every single link span. The code is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('span.menufooter').click(function() { 
        //my code here
    });
    $("span.link1").click(function() {
       //my code here
    });
});
```

I need an event capturing action, the click on the span menufooter has to fire the event before the click on the span link1 fires. At this point, none of the two events is firing. Any hint?

Comment: Why would you need to have one event handler execute before the other, in the wrong order ?

Comment: Had a dull moment with my answer, re-thinking. Thanks @Barmar.

Comment: Maybe explain your intentions a little better for some suggestions on how to improve your app.

Comment: Maybe re-title this question to be more specific about your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could prevent the click from bubbling, and then trigger the click on the parent element so whatever is in that handler executes first (unless it's async)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menufooter').click(function () {
        // fires before ....
    });

    $("span.link1").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.menufooter').trigger('click');
        // .... this fires, as it's triggered above
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/R2U7Q/)

Answer (score 4):

How about only fire event on `.menufooter`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('span.menufooter').click(function(e) { 
        //my code here 1

        // Capture Event Propagation
        if ( $("span .link1").find(e.target).length>0 ){
           //my code here 2
        };
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9QLtG/

Answer (score 0):

Try this `event.stopPropagation();`

```
 $("span.link1").click(function(event) {
     event.stopPropagation();
       ...
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have 1 click listener that listens to the wrapper. You can check the event's target to see if they actually clicked on a link and run code accordingly.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.container').click(function(e) {

        // Perform action when they clicked in the main wrapper,
        // regardless of whether or not it was a link.
        console.log("I clicked in the wrapper...");

        if ($(e.target).hasClass('link')) {
           // Perform action if they clicked on a link.   
           console.log("...but more specifically, on a link.");
        }
    });

});
```

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/WaYFr/